Get the indices and corresponding combinations that contain given term from a list of combinations with replacement
Let's say I have an ordered list of combinations with replacement with n=4 (objects) and r= 3 (sample):
[1, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 2]
 [1, 1, 3]
 [1, 1, 4]
 [1, 2, 2]
 [1, 2, 3]
 [1, 2, 4]
 [1, 3, 3]
 [1, 3, 4]
 [1, 4, 4]
 [2, 2, 2]
 [2, 2, 3]
 [2, 2, 4]
 [2, 3, 3]
 [2, 3, 4]
 [2, 4, 4]
 [3, 3, 3]
 [3, 3, 4]
 [3, 4, 4]
 [4, 4, 4]


How could I get the indices of all the lists that contain a given object and generate all those corresponding lists (order of the elements inside the generated lists doesn't matter but the lists must be in the same order as the indices).
E.g.
Given element 2 and the array above I would want the function to return

indices (in 1-based indexing): 2, 5,6,7,11,12,13,14,15,16
an ordered list of lists/vectors (though the elements inside the lists/vectors don't need to be in this order):

[[1, 1, 2], 
[1, 2, 2],
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 4, 4]]


Of course I could just create this list every time and choose the required elements etc but I was wondering if there is a formula to do this - saving memory etc in case of very large arrays.


you want 0-based indices but your example shows 1-based; 2) what does an ordered list of vectors look like if the contents of the vectors are in no particular order?


Just to be clear, you want a method that directly generates the results rather than one the filters a list to produce the results.

Which language are you asking about?

@Woodford - 1) I'm writing this in Julia so ideally looking for 1-based indices but of course a change would be trivial. 2) Sorry for the confusion - the list of rows should be in the same order as the returned indices but within rows elements can be in any order - not sure it changes much but it's one restriction fewer

@JonSG - Yes, that's right. I'll probably just use filtering in the actual code but thought it was an interesting question.

Here's one approach. It recognizes that you can calculate the next item in the list of combinations purely from the current item. To that end, it uses a next! function that mutates the current item into the next one.
I suppose this could be made cleaner by implementing an iteration interface, but  this should work:
function next!(v, N, n=lastindex(v))
    val = v[n]
    if val < N
        v[n:end] .= (val + 1)
        status = true
    elseif n > firstindex(v)
        (v, status) = next!(v, N, n-1)
    else
        status = false
    end
    return (v, status)
end

function get_from_ordered_list((N, n), val)
    v, status = ones(Int, n), true
    i = 1
    inds = Int[]
    vecs = Vector{Int}[]
    while status
        if val in v
            push!(inds, i)
            push!(vecs, copy(v))
        end
        (v, status) = next!(v, N)
        i += 1
    end
    return (inds, vecs)
end

You could improve on this, performancewise by working on statically sized containers, but I think this should be ok. Benchmark:
julia> @btime get_from_ordered_list((4, 3), 2)
  666.883 ns (17 allocations: 1.78 KiB)
([2, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 4], [2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4]])


So it generates all possible combinations and pushes "good" ones into result?

Yes, but it generates the combinations one-by-one, so there is never any list of "candidate combination", only the list of "good ones".

BTW, I just checked, there seems to be a ~3x speedup by using tuples instead of vectors, at some extra compilation time cost for longer tuples.

I also suspect there is a way to directly create "good ones" without making any other candidates.

In python you can generate combinations with replacement using itertools.combinations_with_replacements
To force an element to be in the combinations: generate the combinations with replacement with one fewer element, and then add the element you want.
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

print([''.join(c) for c in combinations_with_replacement('abcd', 3) ])
# ['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aad', 'abb', 'abc', 'abd', 'acc', 'acd', 'add', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bbd', 'bcc', 'bcd', 'bdd', 'ccc', 'ccd', 'cdd', 'ddd']

def combinations_with_replacement_with_forced_element(seq, elem, r):
    return (sorted((elem, *c)) for c in combinations_with_replacement(seq, r-1))

print([''.join(c) for c in combinations_with_replacement_with_forced_element('abcd', elem='a', r=3)])
# ['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aad', 'abb', 'abc', 'abd', 'acc', 'acd', 'add']


This is a nice idea. I wonder if there is a way to avoid sorting and still get lexicographical order? Even better, I wonder if there is way to create a generator for these so we don't have to calculate all "combinations with replacement with one fewer element" up front.

@JosephWood The tuples that come out of combinations are already sorted, so all we need to do is insert the element at the right position. Instead of (sorted((elem, *c) a better solution would be something along the lines of c.insert_at_correct_position(elem). I was a bit lazy and python's sorted is pretty close to linear when called on almost-sorted collections, so I used sorted instead.

@JosephWood There is no method called insert_at_correct_position but there is module bisect to find the index of insertion.

That’s helpful. I don’t think it is O(1) insertion. Part of me is like: who cares, they are combinations, order doesn’t matter. Thanks for the info

@JosephWood Insertion in an array is always going to be at least O(n), since you have to move half the elements to make room for the new element. bisect finds the index of insertion in O(log(n)), but once you have the index, actually putting the element there is O(n).

It’s not if it is at the end. See push_back

@JosephWood But the OP said they didn't want to insert at the end. They wanted to insert at the right place so the combination remains sorted. Besides, itertools.combinations_with_replacement returns elements of type tuple, not list, and python tuples are immutable, so it's not "insert" so much as "create a new tuple with a new element"
